# How are the new taller table header rows with extra sorting functionality in iTunes implemented?

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nstableview, nstablecolumn

In iTunes 10 Apple switched to a taller table header with a slightly different visual appearance, where the column dividers don't reach the top of the row, and certain cells have extended sorting functionality when clicked.

Here is what i'm refering to:

[image]

Are these a custom control created specifically for iTunes or can they be uses by other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes is a Carbon app. It doesn't use `NSTableView`. You can be sure that's custom.

Comment: For what it’s worth, the iTunes binary refers to some Cocoa symbols (e.g. `NSScrollView`, `NSPopUpButton`) so it looks like they’re (slowly) moving to Cocoa. `NSTableView` is not one of those symbols, though.

Comment: That's curious. iTunes is a cross-platform codebase. The only way it makes sense to pull in bits from Cocoa is if those bits are Mac-only. Of course, they could resurrect YellowBox, but then you'd expect a major rewrite.

Comment: thats too bad, i guess we'll have to roll our own, if we want similar functionality